# Unable to remove '\n' from strings in Python

Tags: python

I have a string `temp_str` that I'm trying to remove all the instances of '\n'. Here's a sample of what it looks like

```
{'A': 'SomeText\n', 'B': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}
```

The '\n' shows up in other places in the string and I would like to remove them. However, I can't seem to do it. Here's what I've tried

```
temp_str2 = temp_str.replace('\n', "")
```

But this doesn't work for me. The resulting string is exactly the same as it was before. Can someone explain why it's not removing '\n' and how to actually remove them?

Comment: you are trying to replace `\n` from the dictionary keys. Dictionary does not have `.replace()` function. Can you share the code you are trying to use please?

Comment: Note that you cannot replace the `key` of the dictionary. Also note that you cannot replace the `tuple` values of a key in the dictionary. You can only replace specific values within the dictionary (string or list of strings). So define your question more clearly if you want a response. Also, explain what you ahve done and what discovery you have done to address this

Comment: for all those who are trying to answer this question with a replace() or rstrip(), note that we are dealing with dictionary. Your answer will need to consider that. And can we replace the key? Will it violate the originality of the dictionary keys?

Comment: @JoeFerndz Obviously it seems He actually want to replace all '\n' character from the dictionary values      e.g look at the key-value pair he gave **'A': 'SomeText\n'**

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you're facing is that this is actually a **dictionary** which you wanna remove '\n' from the Values of the Keys and dictionaries don't have a replace function.

The Best solution is to iterate over the keys and replace each correspinding value with the '\n' value stripped out

```
temp_dict = {'A': 'SomeText\n', 'B': '\nSHX', 'Y': 'Z\nhsh\nSSGHH'}
for key, value in temp_dict.items():
  if(isinstance(value, str)):
    temp_dict[key] = value.replace('\n',"")

print(temp_dict)
```

Comment: This will NOT address the list values for `B` in OP's original question

Comment: absolutely, reason for the line ```if(isinstance(value, str))```. I'm making some assumption in here anyway

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `temp_str2 = temp_str.replace('\\n', "")`?